# Matlab Sound Processing Using Wavread

Tags: matlab

I am trying to change the frequency of a .WAV file using matlab as the WAV file is running 
(sound(y, FS)), and im confused on how to approach  that. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can resample the data at a lower rate (using one of the many interpolation functions, e.g. [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html)).  Then pass that result into `sound` instead.

Alternatively, just modify the `fs` argument to `sound`.